# How to redirect /postPOSTID.html /posts/POSTID/

Tags: .htaccess, forum

I m trying to understand this redirecting but I cant solve this. I want to redirect forum/postPOSTID.html forum/posts/POSTID/

I tried this but i m doing something wrong.
Im reading and thinking it must be something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^post(.*)\.html$ /posts/$1/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule /post([0-9]+)\.html posts/$1/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^post([0-9]+)\.html$ /Forum/posts/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteRule ^forum/post/([0-9]+)/$   forum/posts?POSTID=$1 [nc,qsa]
```

you forgot to put  **?** the sign of variable initiation in URL

Comment: You should make the trailing slash optional. Also `\d+` would be cleaner than `[0-9]+`. I personally would also add an optional leading slash so that the rule gets portable to the real http server's host configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. maybe i better gave an example of a link instead of calling it ID. I want to 301 redirect /forum/post344.html to /forum/posts/344/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok sorry even with tthe explanation above im not able to create the script. Can you please add the wole script?

Comment: [go through] (whoishostingthis.com/resources/htaccess/)
Its better to hide your file location for security so use /forum/post344.html as forum/post/POSTID/ as you redirecting from the client link /forum/post344.html it seems like your file name is post344.html but actually its not, i think 344 is post id and its like variable, its an argument of link. use given answer and if you are using php backend then use `_GET["POSTID"]` to get 344 or any passed argument value in file.

see once if you are not locating your file correctly.

example (phppot.com/php/php-restful-web-service/)